# What does goodness of fit tell us with skewed data?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, distributions, python, goodness-of-fit

> "The goodness of fit test is a statistical hypothesis test to see how well sample data fit a distribution from a population with a normal distribution. Put differently, this test shows if your sample data represents the data you would expect to find in the actual population or if it is somehow skewed."

**But if our population data is by itself skewed,is there any meaningful inference we can gather from it?**

Is there any practical use to it for such data?

[Source: Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/goodness-of-fit.asp)

Comment: Thanks for citing a source. I couldn't get past the first sentence without hitting a poor explanation: "The goodness of fit test is a statistical hypothesis test to see how well sample data fit a distribution from a population with a normal distribution."  That is at best confusing. For the specific problem of testing normality of distribution, there are dozens of tests, not just one. Testing goodness of fit is much wider problem, and rightly includes any statistical situation in which a model and data are confronted.

Comment: The source gets a little better, but is not to be recommended.

Comment: I agree.The initial Quote was what caused me confusion and thats why I seeked clarity.But from what I still understand Chi Squared tests are goodness of fit tests among other things and  are still widely used which seems contradictory to your statement.

Comment: Ch-squared tests are indeed goodness of fit tests and widely used, and I can't see that anything I said stated or implied otherwise.

Comment: Sorry,my bad.I misinterpreted your comment where you said is not recommended.Now I see you meant about source.Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general sentiment on Cross Validated is that goodness of fit testing is no more helpful than plotting the data; that is, formal inference with the p-value does not help. This is because large sample sizes are going to cause rejections when there are subtle differences that don’t matter to you, and small sample sizes will not give the test enough power to detect much of anything.

However, sure, you can test goodness of fit for skewed distributions. The ks.test function in R will test for goodness of fit to normal, exponential, uniform...any distribution X for which there is a pX function. The documentation for ks.test discusses this: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dgof/versions/1.2/topics/ks.test.

The quote you gave seems to imply that the test is for normality. Is the context, by any chance, the Shapiro-Wilk test?

Comment: The quote I found just in context of "What is Goodness of Fit" search Query. It was not mentioned explicitly,in  case of Normality.

Comment: From your Answer,it seems Goodness of Fit does not provide any meaningful inference. But isn't Goodness of Fit underlying assumption in many tests like Chi-squared test?

Comment: Distribution assumptions for tests are common, but many tests are quite robust for decent-sized samples. A joke in statistics is that $30=\infty$. You can find posts on Cross Validated speaking time how little goodness of fit tests help. (I’ll eventually find some and edit them into my answer.) You will accomplish a lot by visual examination of your data and going, “Looks about normal, certainly good enough with a decent sample size.”

Comment: Surely,I will keep this in mind now.You are absolutely right.Now that I rethink,there is little or no use for goodness of fit test if our sample size is greater than or equal to 30.

Comment: Just be careful not to believe in $30=\infty$ too much. Remember: I called it a joke (and it’s one that made me laugh quite a bit the first time I heard it, right up there with yellow and equivalent to the axiom of choice).

Comment: For those of you who are curious, what’s yellow and equivalent to the axiom of choice? Zorn’s LEMON

Comment: What is brown, furry, runs to the sea, and is equivalent to the axiom of choice? Zorn's lemming.

Answer (score 0):

Statistical software was one of the first computer applications widely available. So for a long time there was an approach to use flow-chart style decision rules like goodness of fit tests in quantitative fields like finance. If the test passed normality, "Then Do",
otherwise "Else Do." In recent years statisticians have questioned these types of approaches.  However I think goodness of fit tests are still of value for teaching about distributions.

Comment: Perhaps you can give an example of how GoF would help in teaching about distributions. I’m not saying you’re wrong, just curious what you have in mind.